# Is a particle required after 何か？

Tags: grammar, particles

I noticed that particles are sometimes omitted after 何か. Is there a grammatical rule that dictates omission of a particle after 何か or this is just a conversational contraction?
E.g., are the following sentences equivalent?

> 何か焦げる匂いがしている。
>   何か**が**焦げる匂いがしている。

Comment: I don't think a particle is even *possible* with 何か in this particular sentence.

Comment: @AeonAkechi I think 何かの匂い is fine

Comment: @Akechi,　「何かが焦げる」☜ いいと思いますけど。。「何かがおかしい。」「今夜、何かが起こる！」とかも言いますし

Comment: @Chocolate あ、すみません。「何かいい考えありますか」みたいだと思ったんです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「何か焦{こ}げる匂{にお}いがしている。」
>
> 「何か**が**焦げる匂いがしている。」

These two sentences mean different things and the difference is **not** a very small one at least in a place like this, if not anywhere else.

In the first sentence, 「何か」 is used as an **adverb** meaning "***somehow***", "***for some reason***", etc.  You could **not** attach a particle to it even if you wanted to.

> "There is somehow a burning smell." or
>
> "For some reason, there is a burning smell (around here)."

In the second, 「何か」 is used as a **pronoun** meaning "***something***".  To a noun or pronoun, you can, of course attach a particle.

> "I smell something burning."

One more thing -- the pronunciation.

「何か」 in the first sentence, as an adverb that is, would often be pronounced 「な**ん**か」 whereas 「何か」 in the second sentence would generally be pronounced 「な**に**か」 even in informal speech at least by the more careful speakers.

Suggested readings:

- [Is 誰か行きたい人 a form of double-headed relative clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74104/is-%e8%aa%b0%e3%81%8b%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8d%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e4%ba%ba-a-form-of-double-headed-relative-clause/74133#74133)
- [ってことはどっか Usage in プロってことはどっかスポンサーがついてるってことですよね？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9%e3%81%a3%e3%81%8b-usage-in-%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9%e3%81%a3%e3%81%8b%e3%82%b9%e3%83%9d%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%82%88%e3%81%ad/63209#63209)

I warn you, however, that the author of the "best" answer in the ***second*** Q&A above does not appear to be familiar with the adverbial usage of "question word + か" words.